# Drag and Drop different item text

Tags: c++, qt

I have two QListWidgets , one named “Commands” on the left side and other named “XML Script” on the right side , I am able to drag and drop items from one List to another, How ever, when I drag one item, I don’t want drop that same item text, I want some changed text to be dropped.

Example: In this example when I dragged “SetScroll Command” from “commands” QListWidget and I am trying to drop this in “XML Script” QListWidget , I need some different text to be dropped like 
If I drag ‘Pause Command’ from “Commands”, the dropped item in “XML Script ”should have item with text like “This is a Pause Command”?

How can I achieve this,

I am intending to keep a Map data structure which will have key as “Pause Command” and Value as “This is a Pause Command”. Whenever key text is dragged , value text shall be dropped,

[image]

Comment: @eyllanesc , Thanks for the edits.

Comment: To me, it sounds like you need to derive your `QListWidget`s and override the [QListWidget::dropEvent()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#dropEvent). An [Event Filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) might be the alternative.

Comment: so, if i got this rght, the text generated by the drop event depends on where is that landing...

Comment: The text is always going to be picked from left QListWidget and dropped at right QListWidget.